# ruby - getting records filtered by date

Tags: ruby, activerecord

i have a "Job" module (and corresponding table in the db), that module have a field called scheduled_run (datetime) and a field called user_id:

1. how can i get all the jobs that belongs to a user and are scheduled for today?
2. how can i get all the jobs that belongs to a user and are scheduled for last week?

Comment: Instead of "module" do you mean "Class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the jobs that belong to a user and are scheduled for today, you'll need to search for all scheduled_runs within the today time period:

```
user = User.find(1)  # Will get the user with ID 1
jobs = Job.where("user_id = :id AND scheduled_run >= :start AND scheduled_run < :end",
                 :id => user.id,
                 :start => Date.today,
                 :end   => 1.day.from_now.to_date)
```

To get all the jobs for last week, we'll do a similar command, but we'll switch `:start` and `:end` to be the start and end of the week:

```
user = User.find(1)  # Will get the user with ID 1
jobs = Job.where("user_id = :id AND scheduled_run >= :start AND scheduled_run < :end",
                 :id => user.id,
                 :start => 1.week.ago.to_date,
                 :end   => Date.today)
```

In both of the above commands, `to_date` will cause `ActiveRecord` to treat the resulting `DateTime` as beginning of day.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Job.where(:user_id => some_user_id, :scheduled_run => Date.today).all
```

To find the ones for last week you'll need to specify a date range. I'll let you figure that part out. You'll want to use a "Range condition" or "Subset condition" mentioned in the ActiveRecord guide.

The Rails [ActiveRecord Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) is good to read. Also, see the "Conditions" section in the [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) doc.

Answer (score 0):

Is it plain ruby or are you using rails or other ORM/framework?
I'll assume as much, since the questiontag marks activerecord

It could be done like this:

```
Job.where("user_id = ? AND datetime = ?", user_id, datetime).all
```

more within the Rails documentation here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

You could also use date ranges, just dig a bit around the docs ;)