# Search records within date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Project model has a `start_date` and `end_date`. I want to filter projects with a range of `start_year` and `end_year`.

Current implementation:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def self.date_range(start_year, end_year)
  end
end
```

Comment: Repeat question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534434/ruby-getting-records-filtered-by-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your start_date, end_date are all DateTime objects and start_year, end_year are just the value of year e.g. 2013, 2014 etc., the query should look like this.

```
Project.where('EXTRACT(YEAR from start_date) <= ? AND EXTRACT(YEAR from end_date) >= ?', start_year, end_year)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using AREL dsl for building sql queries like so:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :in_date_range, ->(start_year, end_year) do
    where(arel_table[:start_date].gt(start_year).and(arel_table[:end_date].lt(end_year))
  end

end
```

And then use it like

```
Project.in_date_range(start, end)
```

Would return projects in specified range